# make: No targets specified and no makefile found

Tags: make

I am installing a software named packETH for network packet generator.

After typing the command `make` I am getting the error:

> make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: before call `make` don't forget to call `.configure` with source code on github or call `autoreconf -f -i && .configure` wiht source code on sourceforge.

Comment: Even after calling  .configure the error remains the same

Comment: did you check `Makefle` or `Makefile.am` or `Makefile.in` files on your folder path sir?

Comment: yes I have checked.

Comment: did you try to type `autogen.sh` sir?

Comment: It says command not found.

Comment: use `./autogen.sh` sir

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82707/discussion-between-pranav-and-abu-ahmed-al-khatiri).

Comment: where the package downloaded on github or sourceforge sir?

Comment: FYI packETH is [already packaged](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=packETH) in all current Ubuntu versions. All you need is to run `sudo apt-get install packeth`. You will get not too old 1.6.5.

Answer (score 1):

For builds a source code packETH from [github](https://github.com/jemcek/packETH).

follow the commands with type :

```
sudo git clone https://github.com/jemcek/packETH.git
cd packETH
sudo sh ./autogen.sh
./configure
make && make install
```

The `autogen.sh` will be execute `autoreconf -i` to store Aclocal, autom4te files and other. and the `configure` file will be create Makefile and other for build make c file on dependencies your needs.

[image]

[image]

if you don't have `Makefile` after type `./configure`, you need following the commands with type :

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install pkg-config
sudo apt-get install gtk+-2.0
```

and reconfiged again with `./configure` and then build again `make && make install`, if successfully that will open with :

[image]

Hope this helps.